# UIKIT: InputAccessoryView and Responder Console Warnings

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit

I'm currently designing a chat application that should behave like original iMessage Application. In the application i have overrided the inputAccessoryView of the my `ViewController` to stick an input view to the keyboard. Everything is OK when dismissing the keyboard with `CMD + K` but when dismissing the keyboard with scrolling the custom `CollectionView` with `collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive` 
i'm getting some interesting warnings on the console;

```
2017-12-27 23:43:17.778123+0300 Linky[4750:7371056] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fdc93a37c30; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000c26340>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2017-12-27 23:43:17.778362+0300 Linky[4750:7371056] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fdc93a37c30; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000c26340>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2017-12-27 23:43:21.500850+0300 Linky[4750:7371056] [View] First responder warning: '<UITextField: 0x7fdc8e2a2e00; frame = (8 0; 287 50); text = ''; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000065c7a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000637500>>' rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy
2017-12-27 23:43:21.514121+0300 Linky[4750:7371056] -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UITextEffectsWindow: 0x7fdc8a158a00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x60400062d580>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what is going on?

Thanks.